# Price rule for ONE free item

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

We need a price rule so a customer can get a free item when they use the coupon code. That is simple if they just add any item within a category that is spec'd in the condition, and if they just add ONE of that item to the cart. Doing that, the coupon code works. But how do we set the condition or action to give them the one item free if they have additional items in the cart?

[image: shopping cart price rule condition]

Currently, if they add more items to the cart, the code will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `contains` switch that to `equals or greater than`

Comment: Sorry, I did not clarify the problem. The code works if the customer has ONE item (from one the of discounted categories) in the cart. And if items from other (non discounted) categories are added it also works. But it only works when the qty of the discounted item is 1. If the quantity of that item is greater than 1 the code does not work. Also, if another item from a discounted category is added to the cart and the quantity is 1, the discount is applied to that item as well. So in this instance the customer would get a discount on 2 items which is not what we want.